# How do you calculate a partial derivative when the function is in the denominator?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to follow the steps in the derivation of a Kristoff Symbol for a polar geodesic.  I have the functions:

```
x[r_, th_] := r*Cos[th]; 
y[r_, th_] := r*Sin[th];
```

I want to compute:

$$\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r\partial \theta}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$$
The first part of the expression is easy:

```
D[D[X[r, th], r], th]
```

But I'm stuck on how to compute the $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ in Mathematica.  Would someone please provide the expression?

Comment: You know that `r = x/Cos[th]`, which allows you to compute `dr/dx`

Comment: You know that $r^2=x^2+y^2$, which allows you to compute $r\,\partial{r}/\partial{x}=x=r\,\cos\theta$, since $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Comment: Do you mean "Cristoffel symbol" btw?